# Multiple Submission With XDIME

Tags: xforms, submission

First of all I want to tell my situation. I have an xform of users and my model is something like this

```
<xf:model id="wapFriendForm">
    <xf:instance>
        <si:instance>
                <s:iterator value="myFriendInfoList.items" status="status">
                    <si:item name="friendsToDelete[<s:property value='#status.count-1'/>]">
                        <s:property value="friendId"/>
                    </si:item>
                </s:iterator>
        </si:instance>
    </xf:instance>
    <s:url var="deleteHref" namespace = "/ss" action="deleteFriendListAction">
    </s:url>
    <xf:submission id="deleteSubmit" action="<s:property value='#deleteHref'/>" method="post"/>
</xf:model>
```

And I have checkboxes for each user that in `myFriendInfoList`

```
<s:iterator value="myFriendInfoList.items" status="list" >
    <xf:select model="wapFriendForm" ref="friendsToDelete[<s:property value='#list.count-1'/>]" 
                                style="mcs-selection-list-style: controls; mcs-selection-list-option-layout: control-first">
          <xf:label></xf:label>
          <xf:item style="margin-top:27px;">
                 <xf:label></xf:label>
                 <xf:value>
                     <s:property value="friendId"/>
                 </xf:value>
          </xf:item>
    </xf:select>
</s:iterator>
```

And in the bottom I have two buttons `Delete` and `Move` that for deleting and moving selected friends. When I try to add 2nd submission into form I get error and I dont know how to do both `Delete` and `Move` on same form. Maybe my way is wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.